# Automatically assign names to Zoom dial in numbers

Tags: contacts, zoom.us

We are organizing a zoom convention with upwards of 300 people attending. We need a way to show names corresponding to dial in numbers. Though Zoom shows a guide to accomplish this [here](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360037288352-Adding-Phone-Dial-in-Contacts), there is no link to Phone Dial-in Contacts, as described, under our Account Management. It mentions that the feature needs to be enabled by Zoom. After two help requests with Zoom they have been the opposite of helpful.

Has anybody managed to do this successfully?

My organization is in Canada and we have a Pro account.